# JQuery: handler information empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JQuery and I'm having an issue here. I am trying to replace the submit default behavior for `enter` of a simple form that has only one `input (text)` and an `input (btn)`. I have successfully cancelled the default behavior. However, when I look at the `e.keyCode` or `e.which` they both are undefined. Here's the code:

```
$(".main-form").submit(function(e){
    console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I've also tried this:

```
$(".main-form").on("keypress", function(e){
    console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I finally got something working in straight up JavaScript as such:

```
var main_form = document.querySelector('.main-form');

main_form.onkeypress = function (e) {
  if ( !e.metaKey ) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  console.log(e);
};
```

With JQuery, in console, all I get is an object full of empties. With JavaScript I get all the necessary information. What's the reason behind that? I suspect I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery methods, `e` is jQuery Event object. To get javascript event, you can access the `originalEvent` property

```
$(".main-form").on("keypress", function(e){
    console.log(e.originalEvent);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

to get key code `e.originalEvent.keyCode`